# Web site thinks I'm using small display in when doing HtmlUnit

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I'm trying to extract statements from my gas company (PSNC Energy) at https://www.psncenergy.com

Code is as follows:
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.INFO);
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

```
    try {
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.psncenergy.com");
        System.out.println(page.asXml());
        HtmlInput userNameInput = page.getFirstByXPath("//input[@name='user-name']");
        userNameInput.setTextContent("john");
        HtmlPasswordInput password = page.getFirstByXPath("//input[@type='password']");
        password.setText("doe");
        HtmlButton loginButton = (HtmlButton) page.getElementById("login-button");
```

The page returned is entirely different than what I would have gotten with either FF or Chrome. The OS platform is Linux FC 24.  In particular, PSNC's page as reported by HtmlUnit says "You appear to be using a small screen."

I could try to use a different login page, but that gives a different (Javascript) error, which again is different than what a real browser gives.

My goal is to sign in, download the latest bill from them, then sign off.

Comment: Have you tried setting the driver's window size?